# Query to show whether a record is appeared in the previous date or not

Tags: oracle, query-performance, oracle-11g-r2, query, plsql

I have a table with below structure and sample data:

```
create table TEST_ONE
(
  purchase_date DATE,
  customer_id   NUMBER
)

   | purchase_date  | customer_id   
----------------------------------
   |   1/1/2000     |    1
   |   1/1/2000     |    2
   |   1/1/2000     |    3
   |   1/2/2000     |    1
   |   1/2/2000     |    2
   |   1/2/2000     |    6
   |   1/3/2000     |    1
   |   1/3/2000     |    2
   |   1/3/2000     |    7
```

For each `customer_id` , I want to show whether it has purchased something in `the day before` or not. The output must be like below (I do not want to show anything for the start_date (I mean the first (min) date) which is `1/1/2000` here ,

```
   | purchase_date  | customer_id |   Flag
------------------------------------------
   |   1/1/2000     |    1        |  
   |   1/1/2000     |    2        |
   |   1/1/2000     |    3        |
   |   1/2/2000     |    1        |   TRUE
   |   1/2/2000     |    2        |   TRUE
   |   1/2/2000     |    6        |   FALSE
   |   1/3/2000     |    1        |   TRUE
   |   1/3/2000     |    2        |   TRUE
   |   1/3/2000     |    7        |   FALSE
```

What I've written so far is this :

```
select B.*  ,
     case
       when 
       nvl((SELECT 'TRUE'
        FROM TEST_ONE A
        WHERE A.CUSTOMER_ID = B.CUSTOMER_ID
        AND A.PURCHASE_DATE = B.PURCHASE_DATE -1
        ),'false' )   
from TEST_ONE b
```

The problem is that :

1. I think better query must be possible to solve this,
2. The `nvl function` applies to all records but I do not need to show any flag for the minimum date
3. I tried to sole it with `LAG()` function but I did not succeed

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to join the table to itself on the customer_id and purchase_date offest by one day. Give this a try.

```
select    a.purchase_date
        , a.customer_id
        , case when b.customer_id is null then 'FALSE'
               else 'TRUE'
          end flag
from      test_one a
left join test_one b on b.customer_id=a.customer_id and b.purchase_date=a.purchase_date-1
where     a.purchase_date<>(select min(purchase_date) from test_one)
order by  a.purchase_date
        , a.customer_id;
```